# Python 'No module named' error, how to solve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I'm currently working on a project using Python and I have some problems importing some parts of it. The tree structure of my working directory is:

```
├── checkpoints
│   └── poseConv3DJoint.pth
├── configs
│   ├── pc3d
│   └── rgb_pc3d
├── data
│   └── nturgbd
├── poseConv
│   ├── api
│   ├── dataset
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models
│   ├── pipelines
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── utils.py
├── requirements.txt
├── splits
│   ├── xsub_train.txt
│   ├── xsub_val.txt
│   ├── xview_train.txt
│   └── xview_val.txt
├── tools
│   ├── test.py
│   └── train.py
├── venv
│   ├── bin
│   ├── lib
│   ├── pyvenv.cfg
│   └── share
└── work_dirs
    └── posec3d
```

I'm trying to run the `test.py` script inside the `tools` directory. In this script, I have some imports, like in the following piece of code:

```
from poseConv.dataset.builder import build_dataset, build_dataloader
from poseConv.models.builder import build_model
from poseConv.utils import cache_checkpoint
```

The **init** inside poseConv is the following:

```
from .dataset.builder import *
from .models.builder import *
from .pipelines import *
```

The problem is that it works on my PC, but it does not work on a different system (using ssh). Can anyone help me in understanding why it does not work on this different system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go the full length of creating a proper package out of `poseConv` (although you're already halfway there), the following two options may work:

- Set your `PYTHONPATH` correctly: to the base directory.
- But preferably, don't set your `PYTHONPATH`. Try running the scripts from the base directory instead: `python tools/test.py`.

Even better might be to activate your v-env, install an editable version of your package (which I assume is poseConv into that v-env), and you should be good to go. Because now Python will find poseConv in the right place (which is the one installed in the v-env).

To install an editable version, you can use `pip install -e .` in the base directory, provided you have

- activated your v-env
- have an appropriate `pyproject.toml` or `setup.py`.

Here's a very basic `pyproject.toml` file you can dump in your base directory:

```
[project]
name = "poseConv"
description = "poseConv"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [
    { name = "Me", email = "me@you.web" }
]
dependencies = [
    "sklearn"
]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Comment: Since it's my first time attempting something like this, could you please explain how can I create a proper package please?

Comment: @Neskelogth No: that would be far too lengthy, and is not the answer to your question. If you want to learn about creating packages, you could start with reading through https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/ . (There are several sections of that website; you can probably try https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ for a start.)